# Could not load file or assembly 'VMware.Binding.WsTrust'

Tags: c#, .net, sdk, vmware, vmware-sdk

I am trying work with the VMWare SDK to create a Windows service in C# & .NET that automates launching and stopping virtual machines in the VMWare Workstation. I have downloaded the SDK and referenced the necessary dll files in my project.

```
    VimClient c = new VimClientImpl();

    ServiceContent sc = c.Connect(serverURL);

    UserSession us = c.Login(username, password);
    IList<EntityViewBase> vmList = c.FindEntityViews(typeof(VirtualMachine), null, null, null);
```

I'm attempting to run a basic example but when attempting to connect to the service, I encounter the following exception: "Could not load file or assembly 'VMware.Binding.WsTrust, Version=12.2.0.3593, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

When running as a Console Application in .NET Core, I get a similar exception: "Could not load file or assembly 'VMware.System.Private.ServiceModel".

I have tried copying over the runtime dll's from the nuget packages in my user folder and modifying my .csproj file to include these dll's, but I am still encountering the exceptions.

I am using .NET Framework 4.7.2. and my Target OS is Windows 10.

Assemblies added:

```
    InternalVimService50.Wcf
    InternalVimService70.Wcf
    InventoryService55.Wcf
    VimService.dll
    VMware.Vim.dll
    VmWare.Binding.Wcf
```

```
Stack Trace: StackTrace = "   at 
VMware.Vim.VimClientImpl.CreateClientChannel()\r\n   at 
VMware.Vim.VimClientImpl.Connect()\r\n   at 
VMware.Vim.VimClientImpl.Connect(String serviceUrl)\r\n   at 
VMWareServiceTest.Service1.OnElapsedTime(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) in C:\\Users\...
```

Exception Message:"Could not load file or assembly 'VMware.Binding.WsTrust, Version=12.2.0.3593, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please provide us more information. Target OS, StackTrace and full exception message, .net version, list of all assembly referenced you added to project.

Comment: Thank you, I just updated my post.

Comment: Search this in confg file 'VMware.Binding.WsTrust, Version=12.2.0.3593, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and remove that tag then check. sometime adding  assemblies from different source make this problem.

Answer (score 1):

(First post on SO, but regular user of all the wonderful wisdom)

I just had this same issue trying to learn how to interact with vSphere using .Net.

Solved it by building vsphere-ws\dotnet\cs\samples\VMware.Binding.WsTrust from the VMware vSphere SDK, and then adding a refrerence to the resulting dll to my project.

I just loaded the Samples2012.sln in Visual Studio and build that particular project.

Involved versions:

- PowerCLI 12.0.0 build 15947286 (Not sure if needed, but this is where I referenced VMware.Vim.dll)
- VMware vSphere SDK 6.7U3 (6.7.0-14379537)
- Visual Studio 2019 (16.8.2)
- .NET Framework 4.8
- Windows 8.1

Hopes this helps.

Comment: Thanks! As it happens, I searched for this assembly in the PowerCLI installation folder (where the PowerCLI PS modules are installed) and found it under `VMware.VimAutomation.Common\11.5.0.14898112\net45`. I referenced it from there and it worked!